# Is ぢゃ/ぢゅ/ぢょ used in modern kana usage?

Tags: kana

Since ぢ in spellings was merged into じ in modern kana usage, じや/ぢや, じゆ/ぢゆ, and じよ/ぢよ were merged into じゃ, じゅ, and じょ.

That made me wonder, what about ぢゃ/ぢゅ/ぢょ? They exist, and I found them present in gojuuon hiragana/katakana charts geared at Japanese kids (referred to by the charts as あいうえお　ひょう)

I can't think of any rendaku words that start with ちゃ/ちゅ/ちょ - if anything these sounds invoke a strong Chinese feeling and on'yomi comes to mind immediately.

When I type `dya`/`dyu`/`dyo`, and I hit the `変換` key on my keyboard, the only thing that shows up are the katakana and halfwidth/fullwidth roman variants of what I typed.

Does anyone know if these kana, ぢゃ/ぢゅ/ぢょ (ヂャ/ヂュ/ヂョ) are used in modern kana usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is ぢゃ/ぢゅ/ぢょ used in modern kana usage?

Off the top of my head:

ぢゃ -- 「[御飯]{ごはん}[茶碗]{ぢゃわん}」「[湯呑]{ゆのみ}[茶碗]{ぢゃわん}」「[芝居]{しばい}[茶屋]{ぢゃや}」「[三軒]{さんげん}[茶屋]{ぢゃや}」

ぢょ -- 「[一本]{いっぽん}[調子]{ぢょうし}」「[盆]{ぼん}[提灯]{ぢょうちん}」「[小田原]{おだわら}[提灯]{ぢょうちん}」

ぢゅ -- I can't think of any (except [大手まんぢゅう](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A4%A7%E6%89%8B%E3%81%BE%E3%82%93%E3%81%A2%E3%82%85%E3%81%86) and [ぼてぢゅう](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%BC%E3%81%A6%E3%81%A2%E3%82%85%E3%81%86))

Comment: Interesting! Do you know why 茶 exhibits rendaku? I know the rules of rendaku are confusing but I remember hearing that only 和語 and 音-訓 compounds exhibit rendaku. The fact that ちゃ, an on'yomi reading, exhibits rendaku, is a little confusing to me

Comment: ん？音読みも連濁しません？(Though probably less commonly?)  [者]{しゃ}→患[者]{じゃ}、 [心]{しん}→用[心]{じん}、 [本]{ほん}→文庫[本]{ぼん}、 [会]{かい}社→株式[会]{がい}社、 [産]{さん}→早[産]{ざん}、 [国]{こく}→戦[国]{ごく}、 [所]{しょ}帯→男[所]{じょ}帯、 [試]{し}合→練習[試]{じ}合、 [拍]{ひょう}子→手[拍]{びょう}子、とか・・

Comment: Ohhhhhhhh, I see. The rules of 連濁 are so confusing... I've never been able to wrap my head around it haha