# Are the Hiragana characters ぢゃ, ぢゅ, and ぢょ (still) used?

Tags: hiragana

I am learning Hiragana, and I pulled a couple of charts off the internet to use as study aids. One of them has the line of characters ぢゃ, ぢゅ, and ぢょ, but they are not in the other chart.

Are these characters a mistake? Are they still used? Are they deprecated?

Comment: related, or possible duplicate: [Is ぢゃ/ぢゅ/ぢょ used in modern kana usage?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/80165/9831)

Comment: Note that as a general rule, ぢ is replaced by じ.  Cf [現代仮名遣いでは、四つ仮名は語源通りに書き分けることをやめ、基本的には本来「ぢ」「づ」のものでも「じ」「ず」と書くことを基本としている。](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%9B%9B%E3%81%A4%E4%BB%AE%E5%90%8D)

Answer (score 8):

They are possible in [rendaku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendaku), as a result of voicing ちゃ, ちゅ, ちょ:

- いろ + ちゃや = いろ**ぢゃ**や
- ぼん + ちょうちん = ぼん**ぢょ**うちん

In other cases, though, じゃ, じゅ, じょ are normally used for *ja/ju/jo*.

Comment: Thank you. So if I understand rendaku, a word will never begin with a voiced consonant. Does that  mean when I see a hiragana character with handakuten applied, then it is likely not the first syllable of a word?

Comment: @Rabet No, rendaku is just a process which happens in **some** compound words, it doesn't mean that there can't be any words in Japanese starting with a voiced consonant. You can even see that the word ぼんぢょうちん in my above answer starts with a voiced consonant.